# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition Timeout Not Working On First Request

Tags: javascript

I've checked in both Chrome and Firefox and when I call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` for the first time and never choose `Allow` or `Block`, it never times out. If I call the API again, that one will timeout. Am I doing something wrong? It's not specific to my site, as I can reproduce it right here on SO...

```js
// This will never timeout
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => console.log(position.coords),
  () => console.error('Unable to retrieve location'),
  { timeout: 5000 }
);
// This one will timeout
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => console.log(position.coords),
  () => console.error('Unable to retrieve location2'),
  { timeout: 5000 }
);
```

Comment: So did you hit allow on the first request before actually making the second request?

Comment: No, I did not. I have a fallback that I'm trying to test. It works fine if I hit "Block", but the timeout isn't working. My workaround for now is as shown above: request it twice. The first time will never time out, the second will

Comment: Experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already a pretty old question, but I faced the same issue.
While the calling `getCurrentPosition` twice does work I think there is a more elegant solution

```
const GEO_TIMEOUT = 5000;
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
 console.log('trying to retrieve geo-location, but timed out');
}, GEO_TIMEOUT);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    console.log(position.coords)
  },
  () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    console.error('Unable to retrieve location2')
  },
  { timeout: GEO_TIMEOUT }
);
```

One thing it will NOT do is close the prompt that is opened by the browser to request the permission.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824406