# How to detect timeout of user location permission if user didn't make decision after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, browser, location, user-permissions, navigator

I want to do tasks after the user makes no decision on the location's permission. I have tried the following:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
    let lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    let long = pos.coords.longitude;
    console.log(lat, long);
    console.log("User granted permission");
}, (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    console.error("User didn't grant permission");
}, {
    timeout: 3000,
    maximumAge: 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
```

I have set `timeout` and `maximumAge` attributes to `3000` ms, but it didn't work anymore. The error will only be triggered if the user closes the permission pop-up. How can I detect if the user makes no decision after 3 seconds? Thank you.

---

Scenario:

1. Website is opened by user -> Location alert appears -> user didn't click `Allow` or `Block` for up to 3 seconds -> `Save dummy data location to database`.
2. Website is opened by user -> Location alert appears -> user click `Allow` before 3 seconds -> `Save user data location to database`.
3. Website is opened by user -> Location alert appears -> user click `Block` before 3 seconds -> `Save dummy data location to database`.

Constraints:

- Every scenario should not perform double actions.
- If the user ever `Allow` or `Block`, then perform suitable action.

Comment: There are a few other questions on this as well: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68728926), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74782231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Promisification of our geolocation API would be a great solution in this case.

```js
const getPosition = function () {
  // this will return a new Promise which will then give us Position when it's fulfilled
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // solution-1: more simplified version
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);

    // solution-2:
    // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    //   position => resolve(position),
    //   err => reject(err)
    // );
  });
};

// Simple Timeout function
const timeout = function (sec) {
  // Here we just want to reject our promise so we can neglect resolve by replacing it with '_'
  return new Promise(function (_, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      reject(new Error('Request took too long!'));
    }, sec * 1000);
  });
};


// Promise.race accepts array of Promise and return the first fulfilled promise
Promise.race([getPosition(), timeout(3)])
  .then(pos => {
     let lat = pos.coords.latitude;
     let long = pos.coords.longitude;
     console.log(lat, long);
     console.log('User granted permission');
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     console.error("User didn't grant permission");
  });
```

Have more reading on

- Promisification at: https://javascript.info/promisify
- Promise.race(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: This allows a scenario that would lead to an unexpected experience for the user. If the user doesn't do anything for 3+ seconds then clicks accept, the geolocation data will not be stored. So, the user thinks their location is saved, but it's actually not.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, it sounds like what you want to do is close the navigator geolocation prompt after 3 seconds if the user has not clicked one of the prompt options. **This is not possible**. Why?

The navigator geolocation prompt is controlled by the browser, and it does not expose any kind of method to close the popup.

[getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) only has success and error handlers, and the options of maximumAge, timeout, and enableHighAccuracy. The timeout option is a bit misleading as you might think it's for a timeout on the user's input. This is not the case. The timeout is for the network request through the geolocation api after clicking accept.

[navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) only exposes three methods: clearWatch(), getCurrentPosition(), and watchPosition(). None of these methods are able to interrupt the call made by getCurrentPosition().

Further reading shows that the best practice is to make a soft prompt to ask the user for permission to make the geolocation request, and ideally only after some kind of user input (people don't tend to like prompts jumping at them on load):

- [Chrome developer site](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/best-practices/geolocation-on-start/#how-to-ask-for-users-locations-responsibly)
- [Other answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824406/21148174)
- [MDN on using the permissions api to handle showing the geolocation prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)

If you still want to show the geolocation prompt on load, there is nothing stopping you from doing other actions if the user doesn't click accept or deny on the prompt with a setTimeout(), and clear that on success or error with clearTimeout(). You just can't close the prompt with JS as one of those actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **setTimeout** call before **getCurrentPosition** and clear timeoutID if the user does something:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('user makes no decision');
    // do 1
}, 3000);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
    timeoutID && window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    // do 2
}, (error) => {
    timeoutID && window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    // do 3
}, {});
```

Comment: Will that really cancel the browser-level request for the permission? It seems unlikely. @Jordy I guess this didn't fix your problem?

Comment: @Slbox Yes, this method didn't fix the problem. This code did duplicated task. But at least it gave me the insight to use `setTimeout`.